# Perseguição ou apenas implicancia?

Tags: suporte, voto-contra, serial-voting

Infelizmente em toda organização, sempre tem pessoas que acabam por fazer mau uso das ferramentas, no stackoverflow não seria diferente. Acredito que todos com certa pontuação já sofreram algum tipo de serial, seja de votos negativos ou positivos. O problema se torna preocupante quando fica repetitivo.

No dia 31/05 eu fui vitima de um serial downvote, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O sistema reverteu a pontuação, mas não reverteu corretamente, então acabei sendo duplamente prejudicado.

Agora, fui vitima de serial downvote novamente, em menos de um mês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já fui vitimas outras vezes, mas foi esporádico, mas 2 vezes em menos de 30 dias, já deixa a gente desconfiado de que pode ser algum tipo de perseguição, e acredito que isso não deveria ser permitido no site.

Sinceramente eu não sei como agir nesses casos, além de ficar bastante chateado em ver minha contribuições serem "zoadas" dessa forma. Apesar do sistema reverter, ainda acho injusto usuários que fazem esse tipo de mau uso da ferramenta saírem ilesos.

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser feito ou o que eu deveria fazer, pois estou me sentindo prejudicado com esses acontecimentos.

---

Cheguei a conclusão que se trata de perseguição, voltei a receber negativos injustificados seguidos e com um padrao, sempre aos fins de semana, só que agora o perseguidor não faz serial mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se isso não for suficiente para que seja investigado, eu desisto, eu nunca tive uma frequencia de votos negativos em todo o tempo que estou no site como estou tendo nos ultimos 30 dias.

Comment: O que é não importa. Isto está sendo avaliado, mas não depende mais dos moderadores.

Comment: Poderiam colocar uma possibilidade de ter um recurso que após receber X quantidade de votos negativos do mesmo usuário mostrasse para quem recebeu o voto negativo a identidade do meliante. Ia ser legal :)

Comment: @Everson nem precisa chegar a isso, o sistema consegue detectar um serial e reverte, então, podiam aproveitar esse recurso e punir quem pratica serial com suspensão automatica de alguns dias ou horas, assim a pessoa iria pensar 2x antes de fazer.

Comment: @diegofm sua ideia é ótima, mas não é infalível infelizmente, ainda sim ajudaria muito.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é uma pena que muitas ideias que damos aqui não vão nem pra debate ne :/

Comment: Acabei de tomar um negativo sem motivo aparente, aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215658/4793. 
Mas sobre esses votos negativos, já tive cerca de 200 ou 400 votos (não lembro exato) devolvidos uns meses atrás. Um dia acordei e vi mais de 200 pontos recebidos, fui dar uma olhada era o sistema fazendo reversão de negativos que recebi, aparentemente em série e nos logs dizia "usuário removido" e coisas do tipo. Isso aconteceu mais ou menos 2 semanas depois que reclamei em particular sobre a idoneidade das pessoas desse site... por que estava fod# aturar o abuso..

Comment: @DanielOmine Só não pode confundir as atitudes de alguns usuários com a comunidade, eu também tive votos recuperados após um usuário ter sido removido, não vou entrar em detalhes, todavia praticamente são todos casos isolados e não uma questão do "site", mas sim de mal uso apenas. E claro também não confundir mal uso com um ato legitimo de apontar um problema ou avaliar o conteúdo.

Comment: acho que com 16 mil pontos e 3 anos frequentando aqui entendo bem... @GuilhermeNascimento... não precisa dizer o óbvio.

Comment: Não é questão de óbvio, o problema é quem ler o teu comentário tem uma visão errada da situação, estou deixando bem claro porque isso é um lugar publico, a maneira que você se coloca pode levar a um entendimento bem errado, ainda mais se um novato chega aqui e lê isto ;)

Comment: Você deu negativo em uma reposta minha que não estava errada, cara, e eu discordo completamente da sua atitude. Não que eu tenha tido parte nesse serial voting, acho que nunca nem negativei resposta de ninguém, mas talvez você esteja fazendo inimigos e poderia se preocupar com isso ao invés de só jogar o problema pra cima do SO.

Comment: Poderia ter complementado minha resposta, eu acho que seria válido, mas negativar...

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago  Votos podem ser desfeitos, a funcao do downvote é justamente apontar baixa qualidade, para que o autor melhore. Apesar da minha sugestão, voce manteve a resposta com erros e nem se deu o trabalho de corrigir. Eu geralmente removo downvote quando o autor melhora o post, o que não foi seu caso. Por favor não desvirtue esta discussao, esse assunto não tem relação a pergunta.

Answer (score 11):

O prefácio meio óbvio é que não posso entrar em detalhes sobre as ferramentas, manuais e automáticas, que temos para prevenir, identificar e reverter casos de abuso.

Dito isso, acho que é possível esclarecer alguns pontos, e algumas expectativas, sobre os mecanismos de proteção à disposição de vocês. Talvez o mais importante é que é preciso ter **calma**.

O algoritmo que detecta votos visados requer tempo. A rede tem aproximadamente um zilhão de votos por dia, e os padrões pra determinar o que é *definitivamente* ilegal não são tão simples, então nada vai funcionar automaticamente.

Eu sei que a vontade é que o sistema já entre em ação durante o segundo voto, e impeça que tudo de ruim aconteça imediatamente, protegendo o universo de todo o mal. Mas não é assim que o SO trabalha... o fundamento da plataforma, como um todo é de *abertura, prevenção, e reversão*. O importante é que os votos sejam identificados e revertidos, não que eles nunca aconteçam.

Para casos reincidentes, existem os moderadores. Eles identificam os infratores, e fazem um ótimo trabalho de deliberação sobre o que pode ser feito para impedir que o dano se alastre. Esse é outro trabalho que leva tempo, porque se fosse fácil, teria sido pego pelo filtro automático. Ele requer ponderação e juizo.

A imensa maioria desse trabalho acontece por trás dos panos. Um ingrato trabalho de manutenção, onde, na maioria das vezes, fazer seu trabalho direito significa que ninguém vai reparar.

No final das contas, como eu disse no começo, calma. Os votos contra você no primeiro caso foram todos revertidos. O segundo caso está sendo avaliado, e uma providência será tomada. Entendo a frustração de ver seu esforço sendo tratado dessa maneira, mas lembre-se que o SOpt é um recurso permanente, mesmo que pareça imediato. Suas respostas ficaram aqui, recebendo votos, sendo avaliadas, editadas, melhoradas, por anos.

Mas os ataques sempre desaparecem.

Comment: Entendo q o sistema precisa de um tempo, mas o que questionei é q sofri 2 seriais em menos de um mês, sendo que no anterior, por algum motivo que talvez eu desconhecia, não devolveu corretamente a pontuação do serial. Achei q era uma falha mas pode ser também outra pessoa negativou no mesmo momento que o serial. Meu receio é isso continuar se repetindo(os sérias), talvez com a exposição dessa pergunta, iniba a pessoa.

Comment: Mas não seria uma má ideia o sistema alertar o serial quando detectar, pra que ele saiba q sua atitude não está sendo passada em branco.

Comment: @diegofm Toda pessoa que comete uma infração no site - principalmente as de voto - é contactada pela moderação. Como eu disse na pergunta, pode não acontecer imediatamente, pode não ser notado, mas todos os mecanismos por trás da saúde do site estão sempre funcionando.

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei, quando você é vítima de serial voting, o sistema desfaz todos os votos dados pelo autor do serial voting. Talvez nem todos os votos negativos tenham sido de uma mesma pessoa.

A meu ver, existe um comportamento meio que "de manada" em todos os sites do Stack Exchange. É comum que as pessoas leiam superficialmente os posts e votem da mesma forma que a maioria já tiver votado antes. Em língua de gente: posts com total de votos positivos atraem mais votos positivos, posts com total negativo atraem mais votos negativos. Talvez em algum momento você tenha recebido um voto negativo em um ataque de downvoting, e em seguida outros votos negativos "de manada". Esses últimos não seriam desfeitos por não serem um ataque propriamente dito.

De qualquer forma, a perda de reputação por um voto negativo é bem menor do que o ganho por um voto positivo. Você está entre os 0,86% melhores do mês e com uma reputação consideravelmente alta, então acho que não deveria se preocupar com isso.

Comment: Voto de manada em serie em postagens antigas, de semanas atras? Ai é de se desconfiar de que é algo combinado, o que é pior que o serial em si

Comment: Não se trata apenas de reputação, e sim da credibilidade das minhas postagens. A maioria recebe poucos votos, e com os negativos mau intencionados, muitas ficam com saldo negativo ou zeradas. Esse tipo de atitude sendo feita repetidamente contra mim põe em cheque a qualidade das minhas respostas, que infelizmente por ser em maioria num assunto que o pessoal aqui parece não interessar muito(java-swing), recebe poucos votos para contrabalancear.